# Modify WebcamTexture from unity native plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, native

I just want to pass a WebcamTexture to a native plugin (using GetNativeTexturePtr() for performance), draw something on it and render results into a plane on the screen.

I guess that some Unity thread would be updating the WebcamTexture contents every frame so writing to that texture may produce some flickering effects as there would be 2 threads updating its contents. Because of that I'm using another texture "drawTexture" to render the result.

The algorithm is easy, on every render event:

1. Read camTexture
2. Copy camTexture contents to drawTexture
3. Draw things on drawTexture
4. Render drawTexture (OpenGL bindTexture)

I'm following the [NativeRenderingPlugin](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/graphicsdemos/src/548c5251ddbe/NativeRenderingPlugin/?at=default) example, but every time I try to copy contents from camTexture to drawTexture (even only 1 pixel) the **main thread freezes**.

I think that may be happening because I'm trying to read camTexture while it is being modified by an external thread.

Here it is some code:

**C# plugin source**

```
[DllImport ("plugin")]
private static extern void setTexture (IntPtr cam, IntPtr draw, int width, int height);

[DllImport ("plugin")]
private static extern IntPtr GetRenderEventFunc();

WebCamTexture webcamTexture;
Texture2D drawTexture;
GameObject plane;
bool initialized = false;

IEnumerator Start () {
    // PlaneTexture
    // Create a texture
    drawTexture = new Texture2D(1280,720,TextureFormat.BGRA32,true);
    drawTexture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
    drawTexture.Apply ();
    plane = GameObject.Find("Plane");
    plane.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.mainTexture = drawTexture;
    // Webcam texture
    webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
    webcamTexture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
    webcamTexture.Play();
    yield return StartCoroutine("CallPluginAtEndOfFrames");
}

private IEnumerator CallPluginAtEndOfFrames()
{
    while (true) {
        // Wait until all frame rendering is done
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        // wait for webcam and initialize
        if (!initialized && webcamTexture.width > 16) {
            setTexture (webcamTexture.GetNativeTexturePtr(), drawTexture.GetNativeTexturePtr(), webcamTexture.width, webcamTexture.height);
            initialized = true;
        } else if (initialized) {
            // Issue a plugin event with arbitrary integer identifier.
            // The plugin can distinguish between different
            // things it needs to do based on this ID.
            // For our simple plugin, it does not matter which ID we pass here.
            GL.IssuePluginEvent (GetRenderEventFunc (), 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**C++ plugin (draw texture method)**

```
static void ModifyTexturePixels()
{
  void* textureHandle = drawTexturePointer;
  int width = textureWidth;
  int height = textureHeight;
  if (!textureHandle)
    return;

  int textureRowPitch;
  void* newEmptyTexturePointer = (unsigned char*)s_CurrentAPI->BeginModifyTexture(textureHandle, width, height, &textureRowPitch);

  memcpy(newEmptyTexturePointer, webcamTexturePointer, width * height * 4);

  s_CurrentAPI->EndModifyTexture(textureHandle, width, height, textureRowPitch, newEmptyTexturePointer);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.